Getting "MLGet out of sequence" exception running query through NETLink interface on Windows with Mathematica v=14.1, but not with v<=14.0
Running a given query through the NETLink (.Net) interface on Mathematica versions 14.0 and earlier runs just fine.  But after installing Mathematica v14.1, running that same query in the same way fails with Wolfram.NETLink.MathLinkException (Error code: 3. MLGet out of sequence).  Additionally, I can run the exact same query through the Mathematica notebook client v14.1 and it runs fine.
It is as though installation of Mathematica v14.1 has changed something that inadvertently prevents NETLink clients from running queries (or, I am doing something wrong in my use of the NETLink interface and always got away with it with v<=14.0 but am no longer with v=14.1)
Has anyone seen this, and are there any known remedies (e.g. repair the install of Mathematica v14.1 in some way, etc.)?
Thanks.
